# Recorrer array de preg_match_all() de una pagina

Tags: php

Hola tengo un array dado por preg_match_all obtenido de una web el problema es que no me sale para recorrer las index

```
        $msj_texto = $_POST['texto']
        if(preg_match('#\/hola (.*)#', $msj_texto)){
            
            
            
            $url2 = str_replace(' ', '+',  $msj_texto);
            function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url); // Inicia sesión cURL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Configura cURL para devolver el resultado como cadena
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Configura cURL para que no verifique el peer del certificado dado que nuestra URL utiliza el protocolo HTTPS
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    $info = curl_exec($ch); // Establece una sesión cURL y asigna la información a la variable $info
    curl_close($ch); // Cierra sesión cURL
    return $info; // Devuelve la información de la función
}
            $hola = curl('http://URL.com/botname.php?texto='.$url2);
           
            preg_match_all('#<h1>([^\"]*)</h1>#', $hola, $pop);
            preg_match_all('#<h2>([^\"]*)</h2>#', $hola, $pep);
            preg_match_all('#<h3>([^\"]*)</h3>#', $hola, $pap);
```

lo que que quisiera fuera que me devoviera

> $pop[1][1] $pop[1][2] $pop[1][3] , etc y asi sucesivamente
>
> $pep[1][1] $pep[1][2] $pep[1][3] , etc y asi sucesivamente
>
> $pap[1][1] $pap[1][2] $pap[1][3] , etc y asi sucesivamente

Comment: hay una funcionalidad en los lenguajes de programacion llamados bucles, php cuenta con uno de estos que se hace llamar [for](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.for.php) <- aqui un manual

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que quieres, pero me parece que se podría lograr de una forma mucho más sencilla.

Comment: @Bryro pero no se cuantos valores hay porque solo quiero que haga un bucle por todos los valores y si ya no hay nada mas se detenga

Comment: puedes usar la funcion `count($pep)` para ver cuantos valores hay or `foreach` en vez de for